# Doctrine DBAL versão dev

Tags: php, pdo

Veja so a versão dev é paga :?
Falo porque está me retonando um erro:

> "C:\bin\composer.bat" "--ansi" "--no-interaction" "validate"
>   ./composer.json is invalid, the following errors/warnings were found:
>   description : NULL value found, but a string is required
>   No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
>   Concluído.

Na validação.
Meu composer.json está assim:

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*@dev",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*@dev",
    "doctrine/common": "2.5.*@dev"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O Rafael está correto, para complementar vou deixar um exemplo de um composer.json com a dependência do Doctrine Dbal

```
  {
        "name": "empresa/projeto",
        "description": "Descrição do seu projeto",
        "require": {
            "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*@dev"
        },
        "license": "licença",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Nome do autor",
                "email": "email@autor.com"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pela mensagem de erro, faltou preencher o campo description que é um pequeno texto sobre o seu software. É obrigatório caso o pacote seja redistribuído. E além desse erro há um aviso sobre a licença do software. Se for proprietário é para utilizar a opção "proprietary".

Comment: blz. @Rafael Mena Barreto